# ANN: Learning Vector Quantization not working

Tags: c, algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, unsupervised-learning

I hope someone here can help me:
I'm trying to implement a neural network to find clusters of data, that is presented as a 2D cluster. I tried to follow the standard algorithm as discribed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_vector_quantization#Algorithm): I look for the smallest distance for each data point and update the weights of this neuron towards the data point. I stop doing this, when the total distance is small enough.

My result is finding most of the clusters, but is wrong on a view, and although it calculates a permanent distance it is no more converging. Where is my error?

```
typedef struct{
    double x;
    double y;
}Data;

typedef struct{
    double x;
    double y;
}Neuron;

typedef struct{
    size_t numNeurons;
    Neuron* neurons;
}Network;

int main(void){
    srand(time(NULL));

    Data trainingData[1000];
    size_t sizeTrainingData = 0;
    size_t sizeClasses = 0;
    Network network;

    getData(trainingData, &sizeTrainingData, &sizeClasses);

    initializeNetwork(&network, sizeClasses);
    normalizeData(trainingData, sizeTrainingData);
    train(&network, trainingData, sizeTrainingData);

    return 0;
}

void train(Network* network, Data trainingData[], size_t sizeTrainingData){
    for(int epoch=0; epoch<TRAINING_EPOCHS; ++epoch){
        double learningRate = getLearningRate(epoch);
        double totalDistance = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<sizeTrainingData; ++i){
            Data currentData = trainingData[i];
            int winningNeuron = 0;
            totalDistance += findWinningNeuron(network, currentData, &winningNeuron);
            //update weight
            network->neurons[i].x += learningRate * (currentData.x - network->neurons[i].x);
            network->neurons[i].y += learningRate * (currentData.y - network->neurons[i].y);
        }
        if(totalDistance<MIN_TOTAL_DISTANCE) break;
    }
}

double getLearningRate(int epoch){
    return LEARNING_RATE * exp(-log(LEARNING_RATE/LEARNING_RATE_MIN_VALUE)*((double)epoch/TRAINING_EPOCHS));
}

double findWinningNeuron(Network* network, Data data, int* winningNeuron){
    double smallestDistance = 9999;
    for(unsigned int currentNeuronIndex=0; currentNeuronIndex<network->numNeurons; ++currentNeuronIndex){
        Neuron neuron = network->neurons[currentNeuronIndex];
        double distance = sqrt(pow(data.x-neuron.x,2)+pow(data.y-neuron.y,2));
        if(distance<smallestDistance){
            smallestDistance = distance;
            *winningNeuron = currentNeuronIndex;
        }
    }
    return smallestDistance;
}
```

`initializeNetwork(...)` initiates all neurons with random weights in the range of -1 and 1.
`normalizeData(...)` normalizes in a way so the greatest value is 1.

**an example:**
If I feed the network with about 50 (normalized) data points, that are seperated in 3 clusters, the remaining `totaldistance` stays at about *7.3*. When I check the position of the neurons, that should represent the centers of the clusters, two are perfect, and one is at the border of a cluster. Shouldn't it be moved more to the center by the algorithm? I repeated the algorithm several times, the output is always similar(at the exact same *wrong* points)

Comment: what does it mean "and although it calculates a permanent distance it is no more converging."? What is "permament distance"?

Comment: the variable `totalDistance` represents all the distances calculated in the `findWinningNeuron`. Of course this will never be zero, as the center of the clusters will always have a remaining distance to the single data points, but my totalDistance doe not change anymore, still with a big value. Although the neurons are not in the perfect center yet. So shouldn't the distance decrease? Why does it stop changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not look like LVQ, in particular you do not ever use the winning neuron, while you should move only **this one**

```
void train(Network* network, Data trainingData[], size_t sizeTrainingData){
    for(int epoch=0; epoch<TRAINING_EPOCHS; ++epoch){
        double learningRate = getLearningRate(epoch);
        double totalDistance = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<sizeTrainingData; ++i){
            Data currentData = trainingData[i];
            int winningNeuron = 0;
            totalDistance += findWinningNeuron(network, currentData, &winningNeuron);
            //update weight
            network->neurons[i].x += learningRate * (currentData.x - network->neurons[i].x);
            network->neurons[i].y += learningRate * (currentData.y - network->neurons[i].y);
        }
        if(totalDistance<MIN_TOTAL_DISTANCE) break;
    }
}
```

your neuron to move is in `winningNeuron` yet you update `i`th neuron where `i` actually iterates over **training samples**, I am suprised you do not fall off your memory (network->neurons should be smaller than sizeTrainingData). I guess you meant something like

```
void train(Network* network, Data trainingData[], size_t sizeTrainingData){
    for(int epoch=0; epoch<TRAINING_EPOCHS; ++epoch){
        double learningRate = getLearningRate(epoch);
        double totalDistance = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<sizeTrainingData; ++i){
            Data currentData = trainingData[i];
            int winningNeuron = 0;
            totalDistance += findWinningNeuron(network, currentData, &winningNeuron);
            //update weight
            network->neurons[winningNeuron].x += learningRate * (currentData.x - network->neurons[winningNeuron].x);
            network->neurons[winningNeuron].y += learningRate * (currentData.y - network->neurons[winningNeuron].y);
        }
        if(totalDistance<MIN_TOTAL_DISTANCE) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem :) That a stupid mistake, I'm wondering why the program hasn't crashed...

Comment: I am also suprised - C++ does not forgive these kind of errors. if that answers your question please mark it as a correct answer.